# Tensorflow character recognition

Tags: python-2.7, neural-network, tensorflow, deep-learning

We have been successfully able to recognise multiple digits in a single image using tensorflow based on MNIST data sets .

Now we are trying to detect english alphabets in a single image . We have  found  an  image source of all english alphabets  http://www.ee.surrey.ac.uk/CVSSP/demos/chars74k/

We are trying to generate the image idx-ubyte & label idx-ubyte using sample english alphabets images by using the following link : 
https://github.com/nyanp/mnisten

but we could not proceed on the make command inside the above cloned mnisten folder on Ubuntu & Mac machines .

The error on Ubuntu is :

```
g++ -Wall -O2 -lboost_filesystem-mt -std=c++0x -o mnisten src/main.cpp
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost_filesystem-mt
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [mnisten] Error 1
```

The error on Mac is :

```
g++ -Wall -O2 -lboost_filesystem-mt -std=c++0x -o mnisten src/main.cpp -I /usr/local/include
src/main.cpp:11:10: fatal error: 'opencv/opencv.hpp' file not found
#include <opencv/opencv.hpp>
         ^
1 error generated.
make: *** [mnisten] Error 1
```

We are tying various ways to overcome the above errors .

Can anybody  share the technique for generating the image idx-ubyte & label idx-ubyte using sample images .

Answer (score 0):

You have to install prerequisites. They are listed in the README of the repository:

- OpenCV
- boost (boost/filesystem)

Comment: we have installed both of above listed prerequisites . we tried both opencv2 and opencv3 on mac but facing some or other errors while doing a make

Comment: I think it will be easier to build on linux host. Depending on the way you used to install opencv on mac it may be in different locations. For example on my system opencv installed with homebrew and correct include path (on my system) `/usr/local/Cellar/opencv3/3.1.0/include/opencv`. Though you probably can edit makefile and pass correct include path.